# Passing individual variables vs passing bundle to newInstance

Tags: android, constructor, fragment, bundle

For passing arguments to fragments, I see the best practice is to use a newInstance() method as such:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int myInt) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("myInt", myInt);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

and this would be instantiated as such:

```
int myInt = 123;
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(myInt);
```

If I need to pass more variables then I would have to append whatever I'm adding to the newInstance() method. Example, if I'm also passing a string then my newInstance() method would look something like:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int myInt, String myStr) {
// code to put the int AND the string into the bundle
}
```

Now my question is: what's the difference between the above and below method, which passes the bundle?

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

instantiated by:

```
int myInt = 123;
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("myInt", myInt);
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(args);
```

I have been using the latter method so I can keep the parameter for newInstance() short. I have never seen an example using the latter method and I'm wondering if there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bundle can hold multiple values.

Your first code can only send an integer value to the fragment, using a bundle you can send all you need in a single call.

Thats the main difference.

Hope this helps.